# including of Cilk in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cilk-plus, cilk

How to include Cilk for parallel programming in Visual Studio 2015?
Because there is default installation only for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using open-source distribution of cilkplus?

If so, you won't be able to build the runtime without using a compiler that supports cilk since the runtime itself uses Cilk keywords. If you don't have to stick to Visual Studio, you can try Cygwin's GCC variant (gcc-cilkplus).